# Why doesn’t AX|XB regex match XB in AXB?

Tags: regex

If text "AXB", regex AX|XB will match AX, but not XB.

Why is that? My hypothesis is since | is a boolean OR, if the left member is true then the expression is true and there isn't any need to go compute further. I tried to test it by changing the regex to XB|AX, but AX is still the one match. I guess AX is evaluated first, so actually the order in the regex doesn’t matter. Is that really what's going on?

How can I match both AX and XB then?

Comment: Because the X is already matched in the first time.

Comment: How can I match X several times then ?

Comment: With a regex you would have to get overlapping matches.

Comment: `(?=(AX|XB))` works, thanks for the nudge in the right direction

Comment: @Calimero "*How can I match X several times then?*" - That depends on the regex engine you are using. Which programming language or which library are you working with?

Comment: Your regex will match `"AX"` in `"AXB"`, after which the regex engine's string pointer will immediately precede `"B"`, so there are no further matches.

Comment: @PeterMortensen why are you copy-editing a question that is closed and will likely be roomba'd soon?